# No memory leaks without using @autoreleasepool

Tags: objective-c

I am under ARC and trying to use @autoreleasepool, but I suspect is useless, let's better say that even if I don't use @autoreleasepool I don't have memory leaks, like in this code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSMutableArray* array = [ [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDate* date= [[NSDate alloc]init];
    [array addObject: date];
    return 0;
}
```

I don't use the @autoreleasepool, but if I try going to product->profile->leaks and I run the test to see if there are memory leaks, it says it's all ok and no leaks are detected.Can someone explain the reason of this?

PS: I use xcode 4.3.3 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of those objects need an autorelease pool. Creating them with `alloc` means that they are handled by ARC sending `release` at the end of `main`.* They wouldn't be put into the pool even if it existed. There's no leak reported because there is no leak.

You would need an autorelease pool if you used `[NSDate date]` instead of `alloc`.

---

<del>*Actually I wouldn't be surprised if ARC didn't even bother since all the memory is going to be reclaimed when `main` ends and your program terminates.</del>

Comment: Correct, except for the footnote. ARC makes sure to destroy all objects, because destroying the object might do more than deallocating memory (e.g., it might flush a buffer into a file, or release some kernel resource, or send a message to turn off the reactor's self-destruct countdown). (Of course clang could add a "safe to leak at quit" attribute, the Foundation could be annotated to mark NSDate that way, and ARC could take advantage of that, and Apple could even do all of that without even telling anyone… but so far they haven't.)

Comment: "safe to leak at quit" is a higher level framework behavior that is, in fact, implemented.  When an application is terminated, it gives the underlying object graph a chance to save state, but won't tear down resources that aren't involved in state saving.

Comment: But no leaks are detected even if I substitute that line with "NSDate* date=[NSDate date]". I suspect that intrument application isn't really able to detect memory leaks.

Comment: You get a message in the console about leaks, don't you?